A simple derivation of the Heisenberg limit in quantum metrology
I hope to derivate the Heisenberg limit in a simple way.
Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be random variables, and let $\bar{X} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i/n$.
Also, let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ have equal variance and equal expectation, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\mathbb{E}(X_j)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \operatorname{Var}(X_j)$.
Now my question is: what is the tight lower bound of $\sum_{i \ne j}\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ ? My gut feeling is that it should be $-(n-1)\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$, since in this way we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\bar{X}\right) &= \frac{n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)+\sum_{i \ne j}\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)} {n^2} \\
& \ge \frac{n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)-(n-1)\operatorname{Var}(X_i)} {n^2} \\
&= \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)} {n^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
satisfying the Heisenberg limit in quantum metrology.
Of course, if the $X_i$'s are uncorrelated, then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\bar{X}\right) &= \frac{n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)+\sum_{i \ne j}\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)} {n^2} \\
&= \frac{n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)} {n^2} \\
&= \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)} {n}
\end{aligned}
$$
which is the standard quantum limit (SQL).
But the power of quantum metrology lies in quantum correlation. Hence one should be able to minimize the correlation term $\sum_{i \ne j}\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ to achieve the Heisenberg limit. I am looking for such a derivation, which entails the tight lower bound of the correlation term.

However, there is a simple counter example: consider $P(X_1=1, X_2=-1) = 0.5, P(X_1 = -1, X_2 = 1) = 0.5$, then $\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}) = 0$.
Therefore, I have to add other conditions to make this derivation valid, which makes sense as current conditions do not involve any quantum mechanics.

I don't think you can get it this way. The Heisenberg limit typically refers to scaling of the variance wrt eg the number of input qubits or the number of input photons. You're not really doing the variance of a sample average of a random variable. You're just computing the single-shot variance, which scales as $1/n^2$ with $n$ not the statistics but rather the number of qubits or such. It's quite different in nature than the standard scaling $1/N$ for the variance wrt the statistic $N$ you're referring to here.

What I found interesting is that the standard quantum limit can be derived in this fashion, which is not quantum at all. I am thinking that maybe the "standard quantum limit" is a misnomer, since it can be achieved by simply repeating experiments, and is thus purely classical.

except that no, you can't get it this way. What you're computing has nothing to do with what's referred to in this context. The scaling in Heisenberg's scaling is not related to computing an average over random variables. It's akin to the variance associated to a single random variable $X$, which is however measured globally with $N$ qubits/photons

Notice that if the probe state is separable, then it is identical to an average over random variables. For example, consider the state $\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{2}\right)^{\otimes n}$ which is separable, the Hamiltonian $J_z = \sum_k \sigma_z^{(k)}$ and the evolution $e^{i\theta J_z}$. In this case, the unbiased estimator of $\theta$ has the minimum variance exactly equal to that of where you consider an average of $n$ independent random variables, which will lead to the standard quantum limit.

I learned this simple derivation of standard quantum limit from this article. I think one cannot simply conclude that this derivation is wrong for the reason that it considers a series of random variables instead of a single random variable. There must be some insight in there. What I am thinking is to push this derivation to the entangled regime, which would hopefully reveal the Heisenberg limit.

for separable probes and dynamics sure, it's the same. But the point is that you can't use that formalism for entangled probes. It's not just that the random variables corresponding to measuring different parts of the system become correlated and thus don't satisfy Kolmogorov etc. It's more the fact that to achieve good scaling you don't define the estimator as an average of estimators $X_i$ for each outcome. Ie you never use $\bar X$ as an estimator. The estimator achieving the CR will be a nonlocal function of the outcomes on the $N$ measured parts of the system

I agree. For separable probes, the best unbiased estimator (with minimum variance) is the average. But this is not true for entangled probes. Thanks!
